# How to determine if string from file is float or double in C++?

Tags: c++, parsing, floating-point, double

I would like to parse a file and determine if the number I've read is `float` or `double`. The file I parse is one of the matrices in Matrix Market format (like this: https://sparse.tamu.edu/HB/1138_bus).

Basically the inputs are in this order: `int int float (or double)`:

```
1138 1138 2596
1 1 1474.779
5 1 -9.017133
563 1 -5.730659
2 2 9.136654
10 2 -3.405995
```

etc...

**When I read the float number I would like to determine if the number can be stored in `float` or it needs something big, like `double`.**

Is there some best way of reading and at the same time determining if string can be stored in `float` or `double`?

Comment: Just use doubles.

Comment: Why not just use whatever type gives you an acceptable precision?

Comment: I'd probably use doubles, if it's something that's a legitimate memory concern, then just jot it down as something that can later be optimised and and choose which type you use based on the number of digits read in.

Comment: How will you deal with reading some numbers that need a `double` and other numbers that fit into a `float`? You may be reading `double` values that just happen to fit within the range of a `float` until you find one that doesn't. Usually this is a compile time decision.

Comment: Unless you have a really good reason, you are generally best off forgetting that `float` exists. Just use `double` consistently.

Answer (score 9):

The problem with reading decimal values is that it's not easy to tell just by looking at them whether a `float` has enough precision or not.

For example, 1.0009765625 will fix exactly in a `float` but 1.1 won't exactly fit in a `double` (or any binary floating point type).

You're best off always using `double` when reading in floating point types.  `float` should in general be avoided unless you have a very specific reason for doing so.

Answer (score 4):

You could check the number of base-10 digits in the number that you parse.
If it is more than [`std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10) then using a `double` is a better option.

> any number with this many significant decimal digits can be converted
>   to a value of type T and back to decimal form, without change due to
>   rounding or overflow

Which means you will get exactly your number up to the last significant digit. The rest is not reliable due to rounding and overflows.

Rule of thumb:

- IEEE-754 single precision (float) can store about 7 decimal digits
- IEEE-754 double precision (double) can store about 16 decimal digits

In your example `float` is **sufficient to *store* the number**:

if you will save first seven decimal digits of the float number into the file they are guaranteed to be exactly the same as in the original number. However, if you would do any manipulations on that number, the result is subject to the rounding errors which is the subject of an entire field of numerical analysis.

Comment: What happens if the decimal digits is enough but can't be exactly represented?

Comment: @NathanOliver added the quote from the link. Any digit after the last significant decimal could be different due to rounding. But one can rely on significant digits being accurate.

Comment: That only talks about a number you already have.  If the file has 1.1, it doesn't work.

Comment: @NathanOliver what I mean is that first seven digits are guaranteed to be: `1.100000`

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is definitely possible, but why do you need to?

A gigabyte can store 250 million floats. A gigabyte can store 125 million doubles. If you need to hit targets this high you're gonna have performance issues way before you need more space.

Why do you need the precision? If you're doing a calculator project or something where accuracy is important down to the most minute number sizes you should instead use a custom data type like this to handle numerical interactions:

https://gmplib.org/

The advantage here is that it can be dynamically resized and won't round numbers, which both doubles and floats will have to do eventually.

If you are dead set on your method, however, I would recommend reading your string in and checking the size of the string. If it's 7 or longer store it as a double, if it's under 7 digits store it as a float. Anything over 15 digits will be truncated.